# BlueField(v1) Smart NIC install DPDK

Tags: gcc, dpdk

**Environment**

1. OS Version: Cent OS 7
2. Kernel Version: 4.20.17
3. Arch: arm v8
4. Hardware: Mallenox BlueField(v1) Smart NIC
5. DPDK version: 20.08
6. make Target: arm64-bluefield-linux-gcc

**Problem**

1. When I try to compile the DPDK, it always show error in dpdk-20.08/drivers/common/mlx5/linux/mlx5_glue.c
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtKzj.png)
2. When I use meson build, I found that it is something missing in <infiniband/verbs.h>
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkT8E.jpg)

Do anyone know the correct steps of install DPDK on BlueField?

Comment: can you please check the include for the `mxl5dv_` is shared as CFLAGS via `LIB_GLUE_VERSION` and `LIB_GLUE_BASE`. you can also cross check by running `make -n` too.

Comment: @Vipin Varghese I am not sure where is the MakeFile position in dpdk. Could you please      tell me where I can add the LIB_GLUE_VERSION and LIB_GLUE_BASE in CFLAGS. Thank you.

Comment: as far I remember with DPDK 18.11.7 one needs to have ` mellanox ofed 4.3-1.0.1.0` to get dependency header files `infiniband/mlx5dv.h` and `infiniband/verbs.h` with `mlx5.so` and `ibverbs.so`. Can you please check these in '/usr/lib64/libibverbs' and '/usr/lib64/mlx5'?

Comment: @Vipin Varghese
Yes, I have libmlx5.so and libibverbs.so

Comment: looks like the header are missing can you please confirm with `make -n`

Comment: Hi I hope you were able solve the issue with installing and pointing to the path for `rdma-core-devel`